# A few questions regarding 2D data points

Tags: matlab

I have had some success in the past with seeking help here at SO and have garnered many good hints and tips from you guys. I have run into three problems that I would really like help with. 
Firstly here is a picture of the scatter plot I'm using as input:

[Scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40xS3.png)

Here is the code I've used to generate that exact plot (minus the manual arrows/lines):

[Source Code](http://pastebin.com/G8K7J6gi)

I would like to know if someone could help me with three questions I have:

1. How do I programatically draw those lines I have entered manually given the points above? I've tried a LS approach and it produces ok(ish) results and I am uncertain of get 'tighter' straight lines.
2. There are sometimes outliers in my data that don't exactly conform with the other data in row/column fashion. Is there a way to remove such outliers (as seen in [Point A on the Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40xS3.png))?
3. Finally is there a way to calculate the 'centres' of each of the 'rectangles' given that the points aren't ordered in a specific order? Could one order these points in a specific order to help? Or is there a smarter way?

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I really hope somebody can help me with this - I've been wracking my brain trying to figure out how to do these things and I cannot come up with a solution.

EDIT: Removed the link to my LS approach as it is incorrect in the horizontal direction.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I had a little downtime to try to lend a hand here.  I think I can at least get you started on programatically drawing the lines and hopefully it will give you some insight into tackling the other two questions you have here.

I pretty much copied the code you had and started from there.  What I paste here is what I've added/tweaked after you declared you cx and cy matricies.

Now to explain my thought process and logic.  `Cy` is designed to be the "zipped" matrix of `cx` and `cy` but sorted along the Y coordinate value.  `Cx` is the same except sorted along the X coordinate instead.  The logic and such should be pretty straight forward there I hope.  If not just say so and I'll explain!

Now the `diffY` and `diffX`.  I took the difference of each coordinate (Xs and Ys seperately) since we know there is a pattern here that causes the XY pairs to form a grid-like shape.  I'm essentially banking on the fact that there is a sizeable difference the the Y (or X) value for each line of points (horizontal and vertical).  Once I have this difference between adjcent points I look for a difference greater than 2 (this is post-hoc after seeing what the differences were).  The -1 is used to give me the actual end of the row instead of the start of the next row since we're going to be starting from item (1,:) in our list (makes more sense if you look at the lines in the code).

(This is of course a HUGE assumption and makes this specific for this particular data set.  It can likely be generalized for most grid-like shapes though, but that has to be tested.)

Also a note.  I did notice that later on in the list of points I gleaned using the difference my thought process started to break down.  You can continue to plot more lines following the pattern I have in the code to see what I mean.

As far as your other two questions.  You can likely take the idea that I have here and improve/expand upon it.  I'm thinking that you should be able to snag the outlier by simply looking at all the points in a given row (idx[1] -> idx[2]) and making sure they fit along the line.  Essentially requiring that they satisfy the general formula for the equation of a line that you can get from using the points that are used to draw the line.  You will of course have to have a little error tolerance for that.

Then for the rectangle you can use the ordered group of points to create your rectangles and probably utilize the `regionprops` function to calculate the centroid (center in a 2D world) of a rectangle specified by the data points you can glean.

Best of luck!

```
Cy = zeros(length(cy),2);
[Cy(:,2), IX] = sort(cy);
Cy(:,1) = cx(IX)';

diffY = [0; diff(Cy(:,2))]
idx = find(diffY>2)-1
Cy(idx,:) % Last mark in given row, appears to be slight issue further along.

Cx = zeros(length(cx),2);
[Cx(:,1), IX] = sort(cx);
Cx(:,2) = cy(IX)';

diffX = [0; diff(Cx(:,1))]
idx2 = find(diffX>2)-1
Cx(idx2,:) % Last mark in given row, appears to be slightly off later on. (top of grid though)



%%
figure('Position',[0,0,c,r]);
scatter(Cy(:,1),Cy(:,2),'.');
axis([0 c 0 r])
set(gca,'YDir','reverse')
% Horizontal lines
line([Cy(1,1) Cy(idx(1),1)], [Cy(1,2) Cy(idx(1),2)], 'Color', 'red', 'LineWidth', 2)
line([Cy(idx(1)+1,1) Cy(idx(2),1)], [Cy(idx(1)+1,2) Cy(idx(2),2)], 'Color', 'red', 'LineWidth', 2)
line([Cy(idx(2)+1,1) Cy(idx(3),1)], [Cy(idx(2)+1,2) Cy(idx(3),2)], 'Color', 'red', 'LineWidth', 2)

% Vertical lines
line([Cx(1,1) Cx(idx2(1),1)], [Cx(1,2) Cx(idx2(1),2)], 'Color', 'red', 'LineWidth', 2)
line([Cx(idx2(1)+1,1) Cx(idx2(2),1)], [Cx(idx2(1)+1,2) Cx(idx2(2),2)], 'Color', 'red', 'LineWidth', 2)
```